# Online source code editing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm wondering if there is some sort of element (preferably jQuery since this library is used) which enables online editing in a (converted) textarea. Basically what I'm looking for is a framework for textarea tabbing and syntaxhighlighting for basic online source-code editing that I can embed in my site. Any suggestions? My Google attempts result in RTE-editors having a 'show code' button which is not what I'm looking for, obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) is the serious alternative to ACE. It's used by various projects, including jsFiddle (mentioned in another answer), jsbin and Google Code.

Comment: Aha! That was what I was hunting for when I stumbled upon ACE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something you can embed on your site, try [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/). Here's a [demo](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html).

Comment: This looks neat! Tomorrow I'll check how to download/use it. Thanks, +1 I need it, indeed, to be embedded in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) may give you what you're looking for.

Comment: It does what I want but I can't seem to download it?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.  Are you looking to download some framework and install it in your project?

Comment: Yes I am, CodeMirror can be my solution. Thanks anyway :)